# Making MAMP the default web server on a Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, mamp

I'd like to configure MAMP for web sharing on this Mac OS 10.6.6.  I have installed MAMP, now I'd like to have the files in my user `Sites` to make MAMP point to that directory and access these sites from that web server.  How can I do this?

I will as a next step want to access the Sites folder from the web.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In MAMP preferences, you can point the Apache server to the directory you want to store your files in:
http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/preferences/apache

If you set the Document Root in MAMP to ~/Sites and you have your site in there in a folder called 'mysite' you can access it through a browser via `http://localhost:8888/mysite`. If you have different projects in there, say 'mysecondproject' or 'anotherproject' you can access them through `http://localhost:8888/mysecondproject` and `http://localhost:8888/anotherproject`.

Maybe you will have to change the site URL in the config files or the database of your web application so to make the site work.